# Cannot read the last line of a text file using the system call read

Tags: c, system, call

I'm reading this text file (character by character) using a simple code in C:

> This is the file

the *printf* function won't print anything!

It's just one line of text (but it happens with every last line of a text file).

This is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, bytes_read;
    char buf;

    if((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    do
    {
        if((bytes_read = read(fd, &buf, sizeof(buf))) == -1)
        {
           perror("read");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("%c", buf);
    }
    while(bytes_read != 0);

    close(fd);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a line of whitespace after the last line?

Comment: No...it's just that line of text! I know that with an extra blank line the problem vanishes and I want to understand why. Thank you!

Comment: 1. Check return value of `open()` and `read()` (...and `close()`) for errors. 2. `bytes_read` should be of type `size_t`.

Comment: @Crozin: read returns a `ssize_t` (a signed type). `size_t` is unsigned and casting a `ssize_t` to `size_t` will actually clobber returned error codes.

Comment: Does the text file line have a terminating new-line character? (If unsure, make a hexdump.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *positively* sure if this is why, but it may be because "A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character."

See http://robots.thoughtbot.com/no-newline-at-end-of-file/ for more information, this was an interesting read.

Comment: Interesting reading. I also tried in my shell. I'll add an extra line at the end of the file. I think is the most simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see no error checking whatsoever in your code. Are you sure that you actually open the file successfully? You must check the return value of each syscall and act carefully depending on what error you got.

Comment: @user3102532: How did you check? The code snippet you posted does not contain error checks. Until you edit those into the code snippet of yours I'm not going to believe you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `fflush(stdout);` somewhere after the loop.
The output stream might be line-buffered.

Comment: When the process terminates the stdlib should get flushed implicitly. If that doesn't happen the libc of the system in question is broken.